# how to make rails+unicorn logger thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, unicorn

We've been using unicorn to deploy our application. Everything went fine except for the production.log file, which turned out to be unreadable because the way unicorn was designed. Every instance of unicorn wrote to the same file, causing all the lines spaghetti'ed together.

So is there a way to tell the logger to log independently across multiple unicorn instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your `unicorn.conf.rb`, and change the `after_fork` block to something like:

```
after_fork do |server, worker|

  filepath = "#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.#{worker.nr}.log"
  Rails.logger = Logger.new(filepath, File::WRONLY | File::APPEND)
  ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.logger = Rails.logger
  ActionController::Base.logger = Rails.logger
  ActionMailer::Base.logger = Rails.logger
  ActiveResource::Base.logger = Rails.logger

end
```