# Referring to Rails from the Unicorn config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I'm trying to make a change to my Unicorn config file, along the lines suggested by these three links, to alter the Unicorn logging:

- http://pivotallabs.com/how-to-split-up-rails-3-x-by-unicorn-workers/
- [How to make each unicorn worker of my Rails application log to a different file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551660/how-to-make-each-unicorn-worker-of-my-rails-application-log-to-a-different-file)
- https://gist.github.com/mudge/5063930

They all follow the same sort of pattern (I'm trying the first one), but when I add them to my config I get the same message repeated over and over by Unicorn:

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Unicorn::Configurator::Rails (NameError)
```

The stack trace points to the first use of Rails in the Unicorn log file.  What am I doing it wrong, or what do I need to change to get those snippets to work?

I am using Rails 3.2.14, and invoking my server using:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

Using `unicorn_rails` instead of `unicorn` makes no difference (same error).  My config looks like this:

```
worker_processes 20
listen ".../unicorn.socket", :backlog => 64
timeout 30
pid ...
stderr_path ...
stdout_path ...
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
check_client_connection false
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # No code
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  # Snippet from the links above, error occurs within here
  if defined?(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging) && Rails.logger.kind_of?(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it's environment related? Try adding `-E production` to your unicorn call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that made no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `preload_app true` in your config for the gems like Rails to be accessible from the config file - see [here](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html) for the documentation.